# Vapoursynth output nodes in Python main(argv) function using vspipe

Tags: python, vapoursynth

When vspipe calls a main Python program how do we set the output node?

The following does not work:

```
def main(argv):
   ...
   ... 
   vapoursynth code
   ...
   clip.set_output()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Neither does this:

```
....
if __name__ == "__main__":
   clip = main(sys.argv[1:])
   clip.set_output()
```

Error message is: Failed to retrieve output node. Invalid index specified?

Comment: Do you want **the same** VapourSynth code for **different** input videos and use it with the video file name as a **parameter**? Something as `vspipe -p your_script.vpy your_input_file_name output_name`?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this late answer but I think this needs to be addressed:

The `__name__` variable usually contains `"__main__"` when the script is main target of the Python interpreter, for example when it's called from the commandline.

However, less known because undocumented: when vspipe or any other vsscript-based application runs your script, the string `"__vapoursynth__"` is stored inside `__name__`.

Therefore your check should be this instead:

```
if __name__ == "__vapoursynth__":
   clip = main()
   clip.set_output()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `VapourSynth` script is *not* parametrized with the input video file name, i. e. the input file name is *hard-coded* in your script, e. g. in the statement

```
video = core.ffms2.Source("InputVideo.mkv")
```

you may *directly write your whole script* -

(*without* defining `main()` function (1st line of your sample code)
and the `if` block at the end)

- or -

replace them with

```
def main():
```

at the beginning, and

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

at the end.

You may consider `vspipe` as a specialized `Python` interpreter, so it *knows* (from your command `clip.set_output()`) *which* video to pipe, e. g. in the command

```
vspipe -y -p  your_script.vpy - |  ffmpeg -i -  output.mp4
```

or from which video to output uncompressed video, e. g. in the command

```
vspipe -y -p  your_script.vpy  uncompressed_output.y4m
```